# How do I format my SPARQL for JS?

Tags: javascript, json, sparql

I'm trying to use this http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole and I'm specifically attempting to use the 'transactions in a postcode' option. Here is my JS for the call.

```
var query =[
"prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>",
"prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>",
"prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>",
"prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>",
"prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>",
"SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category",
"WHERE {",
  "VALUES ?postcode {'PL6 8RU'^^xsd:string}",

  "?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.",

  "?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;",
          "lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;",
          "lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;",
          "lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.",

  "OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}",
  "OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}",
  "OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}",
  "OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}",
  "OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}",
"}",
"ORDER BY ?amount"].join(" ");

var endpoint = 'http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/root/qonsole/query';

var queryUrl = encodeURI( endpoint+"?query="+query);

var fet = fetch(queryUrl)
.then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    });
```

But I keep getting:

> "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
>   position 0"

```
.then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json

.then(function(data) { //This line is the culprit according to console

    console.log(data)
    });
```

From looking around, it would appear it's to do with trying to use the .json() method.

I believe the "<"  is from the prefix URLs in the query. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the raw response you're getting? My bet is on XML, not JSON.

Comment: The problem is with the response and not the request, it seems. So check, what is actually returned. It may be an HTML error page.

Comment: Yes - it does seem to be an entire HTML page in the response. It looks like the page you see if you click the URL at the top of my post. So now I have a feeling I'm using the wrong query URL. How do find which is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Web UI screenshot]

---

```js
var endpoint = 'http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/query';
var queryUrl = endpoint + '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
```

---

[image: Firefox console screenshot]

Comment: I shall contact them via their feedback page to hopefully have them expand explanations a little more and define the proper URL instead of having to guess it.

Comment: It is not not very hard to guess, if you are familiar with Linked Open Data... However, not everybody are familiar with Linked Open Data (yet). They write "This is a new service – your feedback will help us to improve it", thus, you are welcome :-).